# Plot of dummy variable with percentages for only one category

Tags: graph, stata

My Stata dataset looks like the following:

| Gender | Age | readsk |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Male | 14 | 1 |
| Male | 7 | 0 |
| Female | 7 | 1 |
| Female | 9 | 1 |

I want to be able to plot the share of women who have reading skill (readsk) which is the results obtained for readsk==1 on using:

```
tab readsk gender [aw=fsweight], col
```

In this case that would be 100% for females an 50% for males

I have tried

```
tabplot readsk gender [aw=fsweight] , percent(gender) showval
```

But I do not want the plots for when the value is 0. I don't want those graph bars. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
graph bar readsk [aw=fsweight], over(gender) yla(0 .25 "25" .5 "50" .75 "75" 1 "100") ytitle("Percent whatever")
```